# Git cloning-Twitter API

Tags: python, git, twitter

I wanted to start working on Twitter APIs using python. I cloned [this](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI.git) repository. Using the basic git clone command. I used the url specified. How do I import the package that I have cloned.
The clone command is something like:

```
git clone https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter.git
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using python2.7 or python3?

In any case you're going to want to install [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) and setup an environment. I also highly recommend [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Once you have your env setup, and you've activated it, you should do something to this effect:

```
(your-env)[me@my-machine]~/path/to/twitter$ python setup.py develop
```

Which will install the api to your local env.

After that, you're free to make changes, and it should continue to use the version that you have installed (I think). If not you could simply re-run `python setup.py develop` and that should refresh things.

Comment: Yes - I highly recommend virtualenvwrapper - it makes managing virtualenvs *smooooooth*

Comment: @WayneWerner only available to *nix users. There is a windows port, but I hear its not that good.

Comment: It was pretty decent from my experience... but even without the wrapper you can still manually activate the environment